# Could not load type System.Runtime.Diagnostics.ITraceSourceStringProvider

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-server-2012

I just did an in-place upgrade of Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2012 and now my WCF Self-Hosted service starts but terminates immediately with the following error:

> Service cannot be started. System.TypeLoadException: Could not load
>   type 'System.Runtime.Diagnostics.ITraceSourceStringProvider' from
>   assembly 'System.ServiceModel.Internals, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.TextMessageEncoderFactory..ctor(MessageVersion
>   version, Encoding writeEncoding, Int32 maxReadPoolSize, Int32
>   maxWritePoolSize, XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportDefaults.GetDefaultMessageEncoderFactory()
>   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener..ctor(HttpTransportBindingElement
>   bindingElement, BindingContext context)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelListener`1..ctor(HttpTransportBindingElement
>   bindingElement, BindingContext context)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpTransportBindingElement.BuildChannelListener[TChannel](BindingContext
>   context)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingContext.BuildInnerChannelListenerTChannel
>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.MessageEnc...

The same service runs fine on a fresh install of Windows Server 2012 (although not fully patched atm).

Comment: I would try reinstalling .net 4 \ 4.5 . any chance your service is compiled aginst a mix of .net 4.0 and 4.5?

Comment: It has quite a few nuget packages that have been compiled against .net 4.0. The service itself is targeted at 4.5.1.

Comment: you should have a configuration somwhere stating which DLLs exactly you need, and if you don't there's a way to specificly request to get the 4.5.1 version... something dll manifest IIRC

Answer (score 8):

A re-install of .NET 4.5.2 as suggested by AK_ fixed the problem.